# Problem Referencing a File from a Project in another Project - ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, system.io.directory

I have 3 projects in a solution, one is a `ConsoleApp`, the other two are a `MyLibrary` class library with one class, and a `xUnit` test project called `Tests`

I have also created a Configuration file in the `ConsoleApp`

The single class in the class library `MyLibrary` gets a reference to the configuration file in `ConsoleApp` and if you run the `ConsoleApp` the code works, but if you run the `Tests` it fails because the path changes to the `Tests`.

Here is the `ConsoleApp`:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myTestLibraryClass = new TestLibraryClass();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the single class in the class library:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class TestLibraryClass
    {
        public TestLibraryClass()
        {
            // get the path of the Configuration.config from the ConsoleApp
            string configpPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "Configuration.config");

            XmlDocument MyConfig = new XmlDocument();
            MyConfig.Load(File.OpenRead(configpPath));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class from the `Tests`:

```
namespace Tests
{
    public class MyTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void MyPathTest()
        {
            var myTestLibraryClass = new TestLibraryClass();
        }
    }
}
```

I am guessing I can hardcode an absolute path string to the `Configuration.config` in the `ConsoleApp` in `File.OpenRead("c:\Users\......")` but I do not feel this is the right thing to do.

One way I got around this problem for now is to copy the `Configuration.config` into the `Tests` project, but again this does not feel like the right thing to do.

Is there a cleaner better solution out for this?

The current exception for this is:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file '/Users/.../.../TestPaths/Tests/Configuration.config'.
```

Which does make sense with my current code.